# Close responsive navigation | React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a header component which manages the state for my navigation component.

The navigation successfully toggles if the user clicks on the hamburger icon however, if the user clicks or taps anywhere outside of the navigation I need the navigation to close.

How can I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
export default class Header extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            mobileOpenNav: false
        };

        bindAll([
            'openMobileNav',
            'openContactModal'
        ],this);
    }

    openMobileNav() {
        this.props.contactModalToggle(false);

        this.setState({
            mobileOpenNav: !this.state.mobileOpenNav
        })
    }



    openContactModal() {
        this.props.contactModalToggle();

        this.setState({
            mobileOpenNav: !this.state.mobileOpenNav
        });
    }

    render() {
        const {nav, contactModalToggle, location, logos} = this.props;
        const {mobileOpenNav} = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="header-wrap">
                <div className="header">
                    <Logo location={location} logoUrls={logos} />
                    <Navigation 
                        location={location} 
                        nav={nav} 
                        contactModalToggle={this.openContactModal} 
                        mobileOpen={mobileOpenNav} 
                        mobileToggle={this.openMobileNav} 
                    />
                    <div className="hamburger" onClick={this.openMobileNav}><img src={HamburgerIcon} /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Thank you will check this out

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald ReactDom is not defined - this is strange, I'm importing ReactDom from 'react-dom'; .... I'm using react v16

Comment: sorry I didn't type it as it was: import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; - still have the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162753/discussion-between-paul-fitzgerald-and-filth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution should work for you.

```
componentDidMount() { 
     document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutside.bind(this), true); 
} 

componentWillUnmount() { 
    document.removeEventListner('click', this.handleClickOutside.bind(this), true); 
} 

handleClickOutside(e) { 
    const domNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this); 

    if(!domNode || !domNode.contains(event.target)) { 
       this.setState({ 
         mobileOpenNav: false 
       }); 
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use react-onclickoutside module https://github.com/Pomax/react-onclickoutside

```
import onClickOutside from "react-onclickoutside"
import Navigation from "pathToNvaigation"

const ContentWrapper = onClickOutside(Navigation)
```

and use

```
<ContentWrapper
  location={location} 
  nav={nav} 
  contactModalToggle={this.openContactModal} 
  mobileOpen={mobileOpenNav} 
  mobileToggle={this.openMobileNav}  
/>
```

Comment: i don't think you need to use an external library here

Comment: Neither do I, potentially listen for a click outside and try to toggle the state? Something like this I guess..

Comment: Hmm this is one of the way he can achieve that. or adding a event listener on part except navigation will work